# Is there a way to set a date and time for a Twilio SMS send request?

Tags: twilio

Is there a way to set a date and time for a Twilio SMS send request, or do I need to program that at the application level?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Evangelist here.

You need to build this into your own application. There are a load of different ways to do it, either with [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), or I like the [Heroku Scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler), but it depends on your tech stack. Let me know what you're using an I can add details of some other approaches in an edit.